# Esav/ Yishmael and Mahalath, and the explanation of the Gra

Tags: commentaries, esav, yishmael

Rabbi Sorotzkin in his sefer ["Keitz HaYamin"](https://seforimplace.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=5486) (vol. 2, p. 13) writes:

> עשו וישמעאל הן קין והבל - Eisav and Yishmael are Kayin and Hevel

It seems that he got this idea from the [Gra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) on Sifra DeTzniuta [(Beur HaGra, Sifra DeTzniuta 4:15)](https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Sifra_DeTzniuta.4.15?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi).

This is, as the Gra seems to explain, why Eisav married Mahalath [(Bereishis 28:9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). And according to this, why was this marriage that bad? Why is this union so bad?

I am not familiair with kabbalah, so I would want to know why this union is bad, according to non-kabbalistic sources.

**Are there any sources, meforshim or other(s) that explain what exactly was the reason behind Eisav marrying Mahalath in light of the end of days?** @Dov provided a really interesting take on this and is there an connection between Kayin and Hevel in this?

Comment: A possible unrelated connection is Esav's long-term plan. He wanted Yishmael to kill his bro Yitzchok and himself to kill Yaakov therefore gaining world dominance, and then he would kill Yishmael (a bit like Kayin killing Hevel) to be the sole inheritor of the earth - see Midrash Tehillim/Shocher Tov 14:2 - https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.14.2?lang=bi

Comment: @Dov interesting. Thanks for pointing to this Midrash. That would explain *why* Eisav married Mahalath.

Comment: Kayin and Hevel are to be understood as roots of souls. They are never understood as reincarnating as specific people. There is a very long list of (very holy) people who "were" Kayin. For example Eliyahu Yitro R Akiva

Comment: @zunior interesting. Care to share some sources that explain the two souls?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1851928/jewish/Many-Who-Came-From-Cain-362.htm

Comment: A large part of the שער הגילגולים is discussing the various roots it spans many chapters

Comment: @Dov that Midrash is interesting. But I still don't see why he needed to marry Mahalath. The Gra says that it is bad when these two "forces" unite, but *why* exactly. Any guesses?

Comment: @Dov I saw that the Gra wrote that Eisav indeed wanted to destroy Yaakov, by joining Yishmael (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Sifra_DeTzniuta.4.15?vhe=Wikisource&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) sv. והוא בסוד אחלקם ביעקב ואפיצם בישראל על שמעון ולוי כמ"ש בא"מ שם בענין השני שעירים: וכן עשו וישמעאל). But I can't seem to understand it. Any idea what the Gra means? This is also for anyone else :)

Comment: This is not a complete answer so I am writing it in the comments. The reason קין killed הבל was because he was jealous of the wife he got. Perhaps its connected